# ApexChart Combo Chart Bar/Line Display issue On Multple Line label And yaxis

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Hello all i'm having an issue regarding the Apexchart. I'm creating a combo chart which is combination of bar chart and line chart. The issue here is the multiple set of dataset for line chart. which the Yaxis of the line chart is not reflect to the value of dataset and also the label of the line chart especially for the datasets that have set of 0 value, it appear at top of the chart.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynXbl.png) i highlighted the image with red color which indicate the issue that i facing. i will provide the jsfiddle here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beyondthegrace/f8b1vjou/2/).

```
var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'All Data',
          type: 'column',
          data: [252600, 203280, 163800, 136458]
        }, {
          name: 'Section1',
          type: 'line',
          data: [0,0,0,0]
        },{
          name: 'Section2',
          type: 'line',
          data: [0,0,0,0]
        },{
          name: 'Section3',
          type: 'line',
          data: [0,0,0,0]
        },{
          name: 'Section4',
          type: 'line',
          data: [29040,16920,0,0]
        },{
          name: 'Section5',
          type: 'line',
          data: [26280,15960,0,7200]
        }],
          chart: {
          height: 450,
          type: 'line',
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Traffic Sources'
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          enabledOnSeries: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
        },
        labels: ['11 Jan 2001', '12 Jan 2001', '13 Jan 2001', '14 Jan 2001'],
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
        },
        yaxis: [{
          title: {
            text: 'All Data',
          },
        
        }, {
          opposite: true,
          title: {
            text: 'Section Data'
          }
        }]
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
```

i wish its not the Apexchart it self doesn't support this kind of method. The line chart value should using the opposite side of the Y-axis, but it seem not work in this kind of situation

i did try on the line dataset value without using any 0 value contain in each set of it, and it works. But once the line dataset is contain 0 value in each of dataset, this issue occured.